# SQL Server 2005: Why do I get alerts for Errors/sec but there are no errors in the log?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, alerts

I am just starting to experiment with SQL Server Alerts. I set up an Alert on Errors/sec with a threshold of zero, thinking that I would get an email any time an error was written to the log. I got a lot of emails! I raised the threshold to notify me when it was over one per second, and I still get quite a few emails from time to time.

As an example, I get emails that contains something like this:

```
DESCRIPTION: The SQL Server performance counter 'Errors/sec' (instance '_Total') of object 'MyServerName:SQL Errors' is now above the threshold of 1.00 (the current value is 4.45).
```

Here is the command for the alert I am using:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'SQL Errors', 
        @message_id=0, 
        @severity=0, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @delay_between_responses=0, 
        @include_event_description_in=1, 
        @notification_message=N'Check the ERRORLOG for details.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized]', 
        @performance_condition=N'MyServerName:SQL Errors|Errors/sec|_Total|>|0', 
        @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

When I look at the log, I don't find any errors. I do find informational messages (a backup completed, etc.) though. Is this alert really "Entries/sec" and not truly "Errors/sec" or am I looking in the wrong place (**SSMS | Server | Management | SQL Server Logs | Current**) for the actual errors?

Comment: If I try `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters WHERE counter_name = 'Errors/sec'` then `DECLARE @I  INT = 1000000; WHILE (@I > 0) BEGIN RAISERROR('%d',0,1,@I) SET @I = @I -1 END` even severity zero errors increment the `User Errors` count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All errors are not logged, a `insert` might be executed that might break a constraint, an error will be raised to the client, but it doesn't mean that it is logged in the error log.

For example if you execute the following t-sql.

`RAISERROR ('This is an error!', 16, 1) WITH LOG`

the error will be logged in the error log, ommitting the `WITH LOG` will just cause the error to be raised without logging.

Errors have attributes which you can use to filter on, such as message id, severity, but you are monitor all by the looks of things. Severity might be what you need.

Comment: So it is giving me a count of all errors, most (if not all) of which aren't actually logged anywhere by default? Interesting...

I do have the option of setting the "Instance" to _Total, DB Offline Errors, Kill Connection Errors, User Errors, or Info Errors. I am currently set to _Total. In the History tab of the Alert | Properties, it shows the Number of Occurrances as 4598. I guess I'll break this down into separate alerts for each Instance type and see what results I get.

Answer (score 0):

I have read about but never used Alerts. Based on this, I believe the "SQL Alerts system" is based off of data writtin in the Windows Application Event log, e.g.

- Start
- Programs
- Administrative Tools
- Event Viewer

and look under the "Application" entry. (Look at the rest of them while you're there, to see all those bugs and errors you never knew about. It's a lot like looking under a rock in the woods...)

Comment: The EventViewer on the server doesn't show any errors in the Application log or the System log.